# Trying to connect discord bot to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

So I'm writing a discord bot with WOKcommands (you may or may not have heard of it), and I'm using MongoDB and mongoose to connect it to a database. The problem is when I run the code it says "WOKCommands > No MongoDB connection URI provided. Some features might not work! See this for more details:" and then a link to the docs, but I DID provide a mongodb URI, and then I also get this error:

```
WOKCommands > No MongoDB connection URI provided. Some features might not work! See this for more details:
https://docs.wornoffkeys.com/databases/mongodb
WOKCommands > Your bot is now running.
WOKCommands > Loaded 1 command.
C:\Users\(myuser)\Desktop\DiscordBots\SpidBot\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:748
          callback(new MongoWriteConcernError(document.writeConcernError, document));
                   ^
MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named 'majority2lTFYH7kkCIuqC54' found in replica set configuration
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\(myuser)\Desktop\DiscordBots\SpidBot\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection.ts:748:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\(myuser)\Desktop\DiscordBots\SpidBot\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:168:12)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\(myuser)\Desktop\DiscordBots\SpidBot\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\message_stream.ts:65:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:777:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  code: 79,
  codeName: 'UnknownReplWriteConcern',
  errInfo: {
    writeConcern: {
      w: 'majority2lTFYH7kkCIuqC54',
      wtimeout: 0,
      provenance: 'clientSupplied'
    }
  },
  result: {
    n: 1,
    electionId: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
    opTime: { ts: [Timestamp], t: 160 },
    writeConcernError: {
      code: 79,
      codeName: 'UnknownReplWriteConcern',
      errmsg: "No write concern mode named 'majority2lTFYH7kkCIuqC54' found in replica set configuration",
      errInfo: [Object]
    },
    ok: 1,
    '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: [Timestamp], signature: [Object] },
    operationTime: Timestamp { low: 26, high: 1649430292, unsigned: true }
  }
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And I'm pretty new to js so I'm really bad at reading errors so I couldn't really understand what the problem was.
If you need to see my code please write a comment, thanks!

Comment: For some reason, your write concern is `majority2lTFYH7kkCIuqC54` while it should be `majority` only. Check your URI string.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Thank you very much! It appears that I've accidentally copied a bit of the URI and pasted it at the end. But why can't I make your comment this posts answer?